# How to divide two values in same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying divide "counts". The requirements for division are the values should have the same batch ID and Carry acronym.  The divisor should be the count value for "Dental -NEBD" and the dividend should be "Added from batch".

How can I do that?

Here's a data sample:

```
Batch  Carr_Acronym  DATE          Count        Datatype
45056  ARM           12/31/2014     20       Added from batch
45056  ARM           12/31/2014      0       Deleted from batch
45056  ARM           12/31/2014      5       Dental - NEDB
45055  CUU           12/31/2014      0       Dental - NEDB
```

Comment: There will be 100's of unique values. End result should be a table with Batch ID, Carr Acyonym, date, "Added from batch/Dental - NEDB percent" (Percent: is derived from the division)

Comment: Do you know the Batch and Carr_Acronym beforehand? Or are you trying to get all results from a single query? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Currently I have a sub query that populates all the information given above. I am now trying to write a another query which will call this subquery and populate the information I am looking for.

Comment: So the above, ARM would be `20/5` or `25/5`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. You can create a temporary table to join on and select exactly what you need. The temporary table will be dropped after the transaction. This will take your current table (in the question) and duplicate it to a temp table. It will then join the two tables (current one in the question plus the newly created temp table) based on the conditions (matching Batch and matching Carr_Acronym) and then divide the counts when the Datatypes are of the appropriate value.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempTable AS (SELECT * FROM MyTable);
SELECT (`a`.`Count` / `b`.`Count`) as `result`
FROM MyTable `a`
INNER JOIN tempTable `b` ON (`a`.`Batch` = `b`.`Batch`) AND (`a`.`Carr_Acronym` = `b`.`Carr_Acronym`)
WHERE a.Datatype LIKE 'added%' AND b.Datatype LIKE 'dental%';
```

Comment: I already have a subquery showing the information above. If I already have that, how would I approach just getting the results?

Comment: I'm not sure I am following... Your question was how to divide the two counts, right? The query above will do the calculation `SELECT (a.Count / b.Count) as result`. Am I missing something?

Comment: well it needs to divide two counts that have a specific batch ID and datatype should be "added from batch" on top and "Dental..." on the bottom.

Comment: @KevinJoseph  Right -- that's what this does. The `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses are how that's achieved... What part am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to user conditional aggregation:

```
select batch, Carr_Acronym,
       (sum(case when datatype = 'Added from batch' then count else 0 end) /
        sum(case when datatype = 'Dental - NEDB' then count end)
       ) as ratio    
from table t
group by batch, Carr_Acronym;
```

Comment: Probably the cleanest way, but instead of `datatype = 'Added from batch'`, might be better to `datatype != 'Dental - NEDB'` (though he didn't speak of the non-NEDB datatypes).  Also do you have a trailing `/`?

Comment: @vol7ron . . . The question is quite clear on what should be divided.

Comment: you are correct.  I must have skipped over the last sentence where he mentioned the dividend.